# How to configure RabbitMQ (in Spring Boot 2.x) so manual acknowledge works

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

So I read all the examples, I have the com.rabbitmq.client.Channel and the @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG), but when I try to call Channel.basicNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple, boolean requeue) the result is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed; cannot ack/nack". I can see that the CachingConnectionFactory does not support any of the acknowledge methods. So my question is what ConnectionFactory do I have to use and howto configure it, so that basicAck/basicNack works?

Spring Boot Version 2.1.0.RELEASE
application.yaml:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${RABBITMQ_HOST:localhost}
    port: ${RABBITMQ_PORT:5672}
    username: ${RABBITMQ_USERNAME:guest}
    password: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:guest}
    listener:
      type: simple
      simple:
        acknowledge-mode: manual
```

Config class:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

@Value("${app.rabbitmq.incoming-queue}")
private String incomingQueue;

private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

@Autowired
public RabbitMqConfig(AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin) {

    this.amqpAdmin = amqpAdmin;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Override
public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registar) {
    registar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(createDefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory());
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory createDefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory() {

    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, CommonAmqpErrorHandler commonAmqpErrorHandler) {

    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setErrorHandler(commonAmqpErrorHandler);

    return factory;
}

@PostConstruct
public void afterInit() {

    amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue(getDeadLetterQueueName(incomingQueue), true));
    amqpAdmin.declareQueue(
            QueueBuilder.durable(incomingQueue).withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "")
                    .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key",
                            getDeadLetterQueueName(incomingQueue)).build());
}

private String getDeadLetterQueueName(String queueName) {
    return queueName + ".dead-letter.queue";
}
}
```

Listener code:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
@RabbitListener(queues = "${app.rabbitmq.incoming-queue}", errorHandler = "notificationListenerErrorHandler")
public void onMessage(@Valid @Payload NotificationDto notification, Message message,
        Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("00000 > " + tag);
    System.out.println("11111");
    channel.basicNack(tag, false, true);
    System.out.println("222222");
}
```

Comment: It works fine with the `CachingConnectionFactory`; the channel should not ever be closed, unless there is a network problem or some violation of the AMQP protocol is performed on it. Show your configuration and post a DEBUG error log (from delivery to exception) someplace. Also provide the version of boot/spring-rabbit you are using.

Answer (score 1):

After starting it from scratch, it turns out that the

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
```

is causing the problem. If I remove it, it's working